# Error in program to display digits of a given integer

Tags: python

I am writing a code in python 3 to display number of digits of a given number.  The code is given  below:

```
count=0.
def fun(n):
     global count_e
         if  n<0 :
             count_e+=1
         else:
             res=fun(N/10)
             count_e+=1
N=int(input())
fun(N)
print (count_e)
```

I am getting indentation error. I do not know how to proceed.

I tried to explain issue with my python code. I expect a reply with a suggestion.

Comment: Where does the error say the problem is?

Comment: Unindent your *if* block. Also you'll need to define *count_e*. Then you'll need to think about negative numbers and the differences between float and int - e.g., what should the answer be if *n == 12.5* ? Have you considered the implications of recursion here?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for?

```
count=0.
def fun(n):
    global count_e
    if  n<0:
        count_e+=1
    else:
        res=fun(N/10)
        count_e+=1
N=int(input())
fun(5)
print(count_e)
```

Moving the if statement inwards to be at the same indentation of global count_e

Comment: Please avoid answering typo-related questions. Instead, flag them as such so they get closed. If you want to be helpful, you can leave a comment indicating what the typo is, although in this case the question is even a common duplicate with many answers there

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid the use of global. Here is a working function for what you need:

```
def get_number_of_digits(int_number):
    int_number = abs(int_number)

    number_digits = 1
    while int_number >= 10:
        number_digits += 1
        int_number /= 10

    return number_digits
```

Comment: The question here is not really ***how*** to count the number of digits. It's how to solve the error in the code (which is not even posted...)